# Standard Notion of Limit for relative frequency to define probability

Tags: probability, self-study, frequentist, frequency

I am self studying probability theory and am reading the book:
Understanding Probability: Chance Rules in Everyday Life by Henk Tijms.

In second chapter he explains about what challenges relative frequency can have if used for defining probability. To Quote:

> Intuitively, we would like to define the probability of the occurrence of the event A in
> a single repetition of the experiment as the limiting number to which the
> relative frequency $f_n(A)$ converges as n increases. Introducing the notion of
> probability this way bypasses several rather serious obstacles. The most serious
> obstacle is that, for relative frequency, the standard meaning of the notion of a
> limit cannot be applied (because you cannot assume a priori that the limiting
> number will be the same each time).

Now I don't seem to understand, why we cannot apply  the standard meaning of the notion of a limit to relative frequency?

The first line explains that we wish to use the value the function $f_n(A)$ will reach as a probability when the number of repetitions of the experiment grows. Then he says this was we bypass some issues. But then he says for relative frequency the most serious case is we cannot use limit's standard meaning.

Why can't we use standard limit notion? After this paragraphs he goes on to explain about sample space, but there also we use relative frequency. If relative frequency has serious issues, why we use it?
Also what's non standard way we use limit in defining probabilities?

The book is freely available to read here:
http://xn--webducation-dbb.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Henk-Tijms-Understanding-Probability-3rd-Edition-Cambridge-University-Press-2012.pdf

Comment: There is at most one limit for a sequence of real numbers. But a sequence of random numbers doesn’t correspond to a sequence of real numbers. If you flip a coin a thousand times, you’ll (likely) get a different sequence than I get when I do the same. If you flip a coin an infinite number of times and I likewise, the two sequences of frequencies we get will be different. We need a lot more knowledge than just the definition of limit to understand what it means to “know” the limits of these two sequences will be the same. (They are, in fact, equal “almost certainly.”)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Your answer raises more questions for me rather than answering mine, sorry about that. As I understand the whole point of limit is to estimate some value which we cannot observe directly. Introducing sequences and their limit raises more questions as I haven't studied or am not aware of limits with sequences, maybe I am, but can't think about it right now. My idea of asking this question is to simplify the language and more importantly understand that a.) what is standard meaning of limit. b.) why it cannot be applied to Relative Freq c.) How Sample spaces help in that case.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews After thinking through your comment, I kind of get it. But doesn't the sequence/order in which we get H/T does not matter and we only use the final count/proportion/ratio/percentage for calculating probability. So if we toss a fair coin infinite times i.e number of repetition n, of the experiment approaches infinity the relative frequency with which we observe H/T is used/defined as Prob. What happens in between does not matter or does it?